# Code Working on Local Server But not work on Go-daddy Server

Tags: php, backend

Locally installed php 7.2 on my pc. & on Godaddy PHP Version is 7.4

that one is a post webservice with mysql database. we need to pass id from request body and it matches with table data and return matching row in form of json object.

```html
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

header('Content-type: application/json');

 $response = array();

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    if (!isset($_POST['id'])) {

        $response['code'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = 'Please set AppID (id) before submit';

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

        $id = $_POST['id'];

// Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
//echo "Connected successfully";

        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM appdetails where `AppPackage` = '$id'";
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM appdetails where AppPackage = " . $id;

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

       
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $op = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $op['error_code'] = 1;

            echo json_encode($op);
            
        } else {

            $response['code'] = 0;
            $response['message'] = 'AppID is not define.';

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    
    $response['code'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Calling method is wrong.';

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: An error message would be helpful

Comment: if i post id then also it excute "AppID is not define block." ( else block )

Comment: @Sangharatna Are you actually getting any value in `id` ?

Comment: @Sangharatna Also, better use PDO for this.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes i got value as well $result..

Comment: @Sangharatna If you are getting the `$result` as well, then I don't understand why `$result->num_rows > 0` evaluates to `false`?